# About normalizer subgroup scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

Let $S$ be a scheme and let $G$ be a group scheme over $S$.

Let $X$ be an $S$-subscheme of $G$; we can define the controvariant functor:
$$
\mathbf{N}_G(X):\mathbf{Sch}_{S}\to\mathbf{Group}\\
\forall T,U\in Ob(\mathbf{Sch}_{/S}),\,\varphi\in\hom_{\mathbf{Sch}_{/S}}(T,U),\\
\mathbf{N}_G(X)(T)=\{g\in G(T)\mid \forall t\in X(T),\,g^{-1}tg=t\}=N_{G(T)}(X(T)),\\
\mathbf{N}_G(X)(\varphi):g\in N_{G(U)}(X(U))\to g\circ\varphi\in N_{G(T)}(X(T)),
$$
and *if it is representable* by an $S$-subscheme $N_G(X)$ of $G$ we state that $N_G(X)$ is *the normalizer of* $X$ *in* $G$.

In a similar way, one can define the stabilizer functor $\mathbf{Stab}_G^{\alpha}(X)$ with respect to an action $\alpha$ of $G$ on $X$; and one can prove that this functor is *ever* representable by an $S$-subgroup scheme $Stab_G^{\alpha}(X)$.

These constructions are clear, for me.

I want define the conjugation action $\gamma$ of $G$ on itself; my idea is declare that for all $S$-scheme $T$, $\gamma(T):G(T)\times G(T)\to G(T)$ is the conjugation action of $G(T)$ on $G(T)$. In consequence, one has that $N_G(X)=Stab_G^{\gamma}(X)$.

My question is: exists an $S$-group scheme $G$ such that this idea doesn't work?

I hope that my question is (sufficiently) clear.

**Edit:** I (hopefully) have clarify the question, as asked me from David Loeffler.

**Edit 2:** No, $\gamma$ exists ever; and moreover: if $x$ is a valued point of $G$ then $\mathbf{Stab}_G^{\alpha}(x)$ is *ever* representable.

I change my question: exists $G$ such that $\mathbf{N}_G(H)$ is not representable, for some $S$-subgroup scheme $H$?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here. Can you clarify what the actual question is?

Comment: I have edited! Is it ok?

Comment: What are you trying to prove?

Comment: I'm searching an example of group scheme $G$ and a sub group scheme $H$ of $G$ such that the normalizer functor $\mathbf{N}_G(H)$ is not representable!